# Laravel run all queues at once

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

If i have multiple queues , is it possible to run all of them in sequence without needing to name each one on [`--queue`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues#running-the-queue-listener) option?

Comment: `php artisan queue:listen` will keep a background process listening for any pending Job

Comment: @Edwin i have tried it but does not work for jobs having a queue name

Answer (score 4):

You could use `php artisan queue:work --queue=queue1,queue2,queue3` to run multiple ones, but it will be a single process and the priority on which queue's jobs are executed first is the order of how you list the queues in the command. (So in this example, first all queue1 jobs, then all queue2 jobs, etc.)

Running the following example will create numerous parallel processes which independently monitor queues without any queue prioritization:

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=queue1 & php artisan queue:work --queue=queue2 & php artisan queue:work --queue=queue3 &
```

I think listening for all possible queues is not supported, because the reason for defining seperate queues is seperate processing. (E.g. do Email Jobs on a different machine)

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem, I don't know whether it will help you or not.

```
php artisan queue:work --queue=low,high,
```

There are 3 queues in Laravel by default; "low, high," The third one is empty; it's not that hard or bad to just add these 3 queues in your queries.

If you've installed a process monitor like supervisor, you can simply add another background process for your default queues. Don't forget `numprocs`, you can raise it more than high and low queue because default queues may be more important.

Answer (score -3):

you could use Symfony's [Process](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) to run the command through PHP.

```
$process = new Process('php artisan queue:work --queue=your_queue');
$process->run(); // Sync
$process->start(); // Async
```

If you will use specific queue names those can be added to the listener as specified in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#running-the-queue-listener).

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=queue1,queue2
```

Comment: Starting the queue worker/listener using PHP isn't what OP asked